# Html.Action wrong behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this controller:

```
public class PostController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SimplePost(PostData postData, bool isRichView = true)
    {
        ViewBag.IsRichView = isRichView;
        return View(postData);
    }

    public ActionResult VideoPost(PostData postData, bool isRichView = true)
    {
        ViewBag.IsRichView = isRichView;
        return View(postData);
    }

    public ActionResult Post(PostData postData, bool isRichView = true)
    {
        switch (postData.PostType)
        {
            case PostType.SimplePost:
                return SimplePost(postData, isRichView);
            case PostType.VideoPost:
                return VideoPost(postData, isRichView);
            default:
                throw new InvalidDataException("There is no post shell for this kind of post!");
        } 
    }
}
```

And in other place I call it:

```
    foreach (var postData in RepositoryManager.PostRepository.GetList())
{
    @Html.Action("Post", "Post", new {postData}) //Call Post method
}
```

So after that I get error:
Could not find the view "Post" or sample, or no handler view does not support search.
Searched in the following locations:

```
~/Views/Post/Post.aspx
~/Views/Post/Post.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Post.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Post.ascx
~/Views/Post/Post.cshtml
~/Views/Post/Post.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Post.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Post.vbhtml
```

(approximately translation from my language to English).

But why does it happen?

I call View from SimplePost and VideoPost methods, why does it try to find "Post" view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC know that action `Post` is exetcuting. When you execute action like a method it doesnt change anything it is like this code was in `Post` action. MVC isn't inform that another action is executing. You need to add view name in your actions to tell MVC which view to render:

```
...
public ActionResult SimplePost(PostData postData, bool isRichView = true)
{
    ViewBag.IsRichView = isRichView;
    return View("SimplePost", postData);
}
public ActionResult VideoPost(PostData postData, bool isRichView = true)
{
    ViewBag.IsRichView = isRichView;
    return View("VideoPost", postData);
}
...
```